# Using Tor in perl script with $mech->get

Tags: configuration, torsocks

I am trying to use the following in my perl script, can anyone tel me why i am unable to connect. Where am I wrong?

```
  my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
  $mech->proxy(['http'], 'http://localhost:9050');
  $mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/".           $btcaddress);    # Check transactions on my addresses
  my $getreceived = $mech->content;
```

I have decided to use Net::SOCKS, is this the correct way to implement this into the perl script?

```
  my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
  my $sock = new Net::SOCKS(socks_addr => '127.0.0.1',
            socks_port => 9050,
            user_id => 'the_user',
            user_password => 'the_password',
            force_nonanonymous => 1,
            protocol_version => 5);


  $mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/".$btcaddress);   # Check transactions on bitcoin address
  my $getreceived = $mech->content;

  $mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/addressbalance/".$btcaddress);   # Check balance on bitcoin address
  my $addressbalance = $mech->content;

  # send it back to the parent process
  $pm->finish(0, [ $getreceived, $addressbalance, $btcaddress, $private, $passphrase ]);  
  $sock->close();
```

Comment: Tor is not an HTTP proxy, it is a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: how would i input that into the above, i have tried replacing http with socks

Comment: I've no idea, you'd need to see if the library supported SOCKS, or just wrap perl with `torsocks`.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like [this](http://mlawire.blogspot.ru/2009/07/using-lwp-with-tor.html) - citing the code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
  agent => q{Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; YPC 3.2.0; .NET 
CLR 1.1.4322)},
);
$ua->proxy([qw/ http https /] => 'socks://localhost:9050'); # Tor proxy
$ua->cookie_jar({});
my $rsp = $ua->get('http://www.yahoo.com/');
print $rsp->content;
```